# Artefacts when rendering to a framebuffer with alpha blending using WebGL2

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am trying to draw 2D metaballs using WebGL2. I render a bunch of quads with transparent radial gradient and `gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` to a separate framebuffer. I then use the resulting texture in a fullscreen quad, where I decide if pixel should be rendered based on it's alpha value like so:

```c
vec4 inputColor = texture(u_texture, v_uv);

float cutoffThreshold = 0.14;

float cutoff = step(cutoffThreshold, inputColor.a);
float threshold = 0.005;

outputColor = mix(
  vec4(1, 0, 0, 1),
  vec4(0, 0, 1, 1),
  cutoff
);
```

While this kinda works, it produces really noticeable artefacts along the edges:

[image]

I think the problem lays in my blending operation. I tried enabling blending only when drawing to my framebuffer and disableing it when rendering my main quad without much success.

Here is my program:

```js
const CONFIG = {
  ballsCount: 10,
  ballRadius: isMobileBrowser() ? 75 : 200,
  gravity: 0.1,
  lineWidth: innerWidth / 2,
  startVelocityX: { min: 0, max: 0.1 },
  startVelocityY: { min: 1, max: 3 },
}

const contentWrapper = document.querySelector('.content')
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2')

const dpr = devicePixelRatio > 2.5 ? 2.5 : devicePixelRatio

if (!gl) {
  showWebGL2NotSupported()
}

const lineVertexArrayObject = gl.createVertexArray()
const quadVertexArrayObject = gl.createVertexArray()
const ballsVertexArrayObject = gl.createVertexArray()

const ballsOffsetsBuffer = gl.createBuffer()

let oldTime = 0
let lineAngle = 0

// WebGL Programs
let lineWebGLProgram
let quadWebGLProgram
let ballsWebGLProgram

let quadTextureUniformLoc
let lineAngleUniformLoc

let lineVertexArray
let ballsOffsetsArray
// Not for rendering, just storing the balls velocities
let ballsVelocitiesArray

/* ------- Create horizontal line WebGL program ------- */
{
  const vertexShader = makeWebglShader(gl, {
    shaderType: gl.VERTEX_SHADER,
    shaderSource: `#version 300 es
      uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
      uniform vec2 u_resolution;
      uniform float u_angle;

      in vec4 a_position;

      mat4 rotationZ( in float angle ) {
        return mat4(
          cos(angle),   -sin(angle), 0.0, 0.0,
          sin(angle),    cos(angle), 0.0,   0.0,
          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        );
      }

      void main () {
        gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * (rotationZ(u_angle) * a_position + vec4(u_resolution.xy / 2.0, 0.0, 1.0));
      }
    `,
  })
  const fragmentShader = makeWebglShader(gl, {
    shaderType: gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER,
    shaderSource: `#version 300 es
      precision highp float;

      out vec4 outputColor;

      void main () {
        outputColor = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
      }
    `,
  })
  lineWebGLProgram = makeWebglProram(gl, {
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
  })
}

/* ------- Create and assign horizontal line WebGL attributes ------- */
{
  lineVertexArray = new Float32Array([-CONFIG.lineWidth / 2, 0, CONFIG.lineWidth / 2, 0])

  
  const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()

  const a_position = gl.getAttribLocation(lineWebGLProgram, 'a_position')
  
  gl.bindVertexArray(lineVertexArrayObject)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, lineVertexArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_position)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

  gl.bindVertexArray(null)
}

/* ------- Create metaballs WebGL program ------- */
{
  const vertexShader = makeWebglShader(gl, {
    shaderType: gl.VERTEX_SHADER,
    shaderSource: `#version 300 es
      uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
      
      in vec4 a_position;
      in vec4 a_offsetPosition;
      in vec2 a_uv;

      out vec2 v_uv;

      void main () {
        vec4 correctOffsetedPosition = a_offsetPosition + a_position;
        gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * correctOffsetedPosition;
        v_uv = a_uv;
      }
    `
  })
  const fragmentShader = makeWebglShader(gl, {
    shaderType: gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER,
    shaderSource: `#version 300 es
      precision highp float;

      in vec2 v_uv;

      out vec4 outputColor;

      void main () {
        float dist = distance(v_uv, vec2(0.5));
        float c = 0.5 - dist;
        outputColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), c);
      }
    `
  })
  ballsWebGLProgram = makeWebglProram(gl, {
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
  })
}

/* ------- Create and assign metaballs WebGL attributes ------- */
{
  const vertexArray = new Float32Array([
    -CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,  CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,
     CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,  CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,
     CONFIG.ballRadius / 2, -CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,
    -CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,  CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,
     CONFIG.ballRadius / 2, -CONFIG.ballRadius / 2,
    -CONFIG.ballRadius / 2, -CONFIG.ballRadius / 2
  ])
  const uvsArray = makeQuadUVs()

  ballsOffsetsArray = new Float32Array(CONFIG.ballsCount * 2)
  ballsVelocitiesArray = new Float32Array(CONFIG.ballsCount * 2)

  for (let i = 0; i < CONFIG.ballsCount; i++) {
    ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0] = Math.random() * innerWidth
    ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 1] = Math.random() * innerHeight

    ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 0] = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * CONFIG.startVelocityX.max + CONFIG.startVelocityX.min
    ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 1] = Math.random() * CONFIG.startVelocityY.max + CONFIG.startVelocityY.min
  }
  const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  const uvsBuffer = gl.createBuffer()

  const a_position = gl.getAttribLocation(ballsWebGLProgram, 'a_position')
  const a_uv = gl.getAttribLocation(ballsWebGLProgram, 'a_uv')
  const a_offsetPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(ballsWebGLProgram, 'a_offsetPosition')

  gl.bindVertexArray(ballsVertexArrayObject)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_position)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvsBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvsArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_uv)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_uv, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ballsOffsetsBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ballsOffsetsArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_offsetPosition)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_offsetPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
  gl.vertexAttribDivisor(a_offsetPosition, 1)

  gl.bindVertexArray(null)

}

/* ------- Create fullscreen quad WebGL program ------- */
{
  const vertexShader = makeWebglShader(gl, {
    shaderType: gl.VERTEX_SHADER,
    shaderSource: `#version 300 es
      uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;

      in vec4 a_position;
      in vec2 a_uv;

      out vec2 v_uv;

      void main () {
        gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * a_position;
        v_uv = a_uv;
      }
    `
  })
  const fragmentShader = makeWebglShader(gl, {
    shaderType: gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER,
    shaderSource: `#version 300 es
      precision highp float;

      uniform sampler2D u_texture;

      in vec2 v_uv;

      out vec4 outputColor;

      void main () {
        vec4 inputColor = texture(u_texture, v_uv);

        float cutoffThreshold = 0.14;

        float cutoff = step(cutoffThreshold, inputColor.a);
        float threshold = 0.005;

        outputColor = mix(
          vec4(1, 0, 0, 1),
          vec4(0, 0, 1, 1),
          cutoff
        );

        cutoffThreshold += 0.001;

        cutoff = smoothstep(cutoffThreshold - threshold, cutoffThreshold + threshold, inputColor.a);
        outputColor = mix(
          outputColor,
          vec4(1, 0, 0, 1),
          cutoff
        );

        cutoffThreshold += 0.05;

        cutoff = smoothstep(cutoffThreshold - threshold, cutoffThreshold + threshold, inputColor.a);
        outputColor = mix(
          outputColor,
          vec4(0, 1, 0, 1),
          cutoff
        );

        // outputColor = mix(inputColor, mix(baseColor, metaballsColor, cutoff), 0.3);

        // outputColor = inputColor;
      }
    `
  })
  quadWebGLProgram = makeWebglProram(gl, {
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
  })
}

/* ------- Create and assign fullscreen quad WebGL attributes ------- */
{
  const vertexArray = new Float32Array([
    0, innerHeight / 2,
    innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2,
    innerWidth / 2, 0,
    0, innerHeight / 2,
    innerWidth / 2, 0,
    0, 0
  ])
  const uvsArray = makeQuadUVs()

  const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  const uvsBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  
  const a_position = gl.getAttribLocation(quadWebGLProgram, 'a_position')
  const a_uv = gl.getAttribLocation(quadWebGLProgram, 'a_uv')

  gl.bindVertexArray(quadVertexArrayObject)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_position)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvsBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvsArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_uv)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_uv, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

  gl.bindVertexArray(null)
}

/* ------- Create WebGL texture to render to ------- */
  gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float')
  gl.getExtension('EXT_float_blend')
  gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear')


const targetTextureWidth = innerWidth * dpr
const targetTextureHeight = innerHeight * dpr
const targetTexture = gl.createTexture()
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture)
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32F, targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null)
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null)

/* ------- Create WebGL framebuffer to render to ------- */
const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer()
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer)
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture, 0)
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null)

init()
function init () {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas)
  resize()
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize)


  gl.enable(gl.BLEND)
  gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
  // gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_SUBTRACT)

  const projectionMatrix = makeProjectionMatrix(innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2)

  let u_projectionMatrix

  gl.useProgram(ballsWebGLProgram)
  u_projectionMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(ballsWebGLProgram, 'u_projectionMatrix')
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_projectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix)
  gl.useProgram(null)

  gl.useProgram(quadWebGLProgram)
  quadTextureUniformLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(quadWebGLProgram, 'u_texture')
  gl.uniform1i(quadTextureUniformLoc, 0)
  u_projectionMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(quadWebGLProgram, 'u_projectionMatrix')
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_projectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix)
  gl.useProgram(null)

  gl.useProgram(lineWebGLProgram)
  u_projectionMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(lineWebGLProgram, 'u_projectionMatrix')
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_projectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix)

  const u_resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(lineWebGLProgram, 'u_resolution')
  gl.uniform2f(u_resolution, innerWidth, innerHeight)

  lineAngleUniformLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(lineWebGLProgram, 'u_angle')
  gl.uniform1f(lineAngleUniformLoc, lineAngle * Math.PI / 180)

  gl.useProgram(null)

  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame)
  
}

let a = true
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  a = !a
})

function renderFrame (ts) {
  const dt = ts - oldTime
  oldTime = ts

  for (let i = 0; i < CONFIG.ballsCount; i++) {
    ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 1] += CONFIG.gravity
    ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0] += ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 0]
    ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 1] += ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 1]


    if (ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0] < CONFIG.ballRadius / 2) {
      ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0] = CONFIG.ballRadius / 2
      ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 0] *= -1
    }
    if (ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0] > innerWidth - CONFIG.ballRadius / 2) {
      ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0] = innerWidth - CONFIG.ballRadius / 2
      ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 0] *= -1
    }

    if (ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 1] - CONFIG.ballRadius > innerHeight) {
      ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 1] = -CONFIG.ballRadius
      ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 1] = 5 + Math.random() * 3
    }
  }

  checkLine()

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ballsOffsetsBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ballsOffsetsArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)
  
  if (a) {
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer)
  }

  gl.viewport(0, 0, targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight)
  gl.clearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0)
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

  gl.bindVertexArray(ballsVertexArrayObject)
  gl.useProgram(ballsWebGLProgram)
  gl.drawArraysInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6, CONFIG.ballsCount)
  gl.bindVertexArray(null)

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null)

  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  if (a) {
    gl.bindVertexArray(quadVertexArrayObject)
    gl.useProgram(quadWebGLProgram)
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture)
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true)
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
    gl.useProgram(null)
    gl.bindVertexArray(null)
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null)
  }

  lineAngle = Math.sin(ts * 0.001) * 30

  gl.bindVertexArray(lineVertexArrayObject)
  gl.useProgram(lineWebGLProgram)
  gl.uniform1f(lineAngleUniformLoc, -lineAngle * Math.PI / 180)
  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 2)
  gl.useProgram(null)
  gl.bindVertexArray(null)

  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame)
}

function getLineBounds () {
  const x1 = lineVertexArray[0]
  const y1 = lineVertexArray[1]
  const x2 = lineVertexArray[2]
  const y2 = lineVertexArray[3]
  if (lineAngle === 0) {
    const minX = Math.min(x1, x2)
    const minY = Math.min(y1, y2)
    const maxX = Math.max(x1, x2)
    const maxY = Math.max(y1, y2)
    return {
      x: x1 + minX,
      y: y1 + minY,
      width: maxX - minX,
      height: maxY - minY,
    }
  } else {
    const rotation = lineAngle * Math.PI / 180
    const sin = Math.sin(rotation)
    const cos = Math.cos(rotation)
    const x1r = cos * x1 + sin * y1
    const x2r = cos * x2 + sin * y2
    const y1r = cos * y1 + sin * x1
    const y2r = cos * y2 + sin * x2
    const x = innerWidth / 2 + x1 + Math.min(x1r, x2r) + CONFIG.lineWidth / 2
    const y = innerHeight / 2 + y1 + Math.min(y1r, y2r) + CONFIG.lineWidth / 2
    const width = Math.max(x1r, x2r) - Math.min(x1r, x2r)
    const height = Math.max(y1r, y2r) - Math.min(y1r, y2r)
    return {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height,
    }
  }
}

function checkLine () {
  const lineBounds = getLineBounds()
  const ballRadius = CONFIG.ballRadius / 7

  for (let i = 0; i < CONFIG.ballsCount; i++) {
    const ballx = ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0]
    const bally = ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 1]
    const ballvx = ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 0]
    const ballvy = ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 1]
    if (ballx + ballRadius / 2 > lineBounds.x && ballx - ballRadius / 2 < lineBounds.x + lineBounds.width) {
    
      const lineRotation = lineAngle * Math.PI / 180
      const cos = Math.cos(lineRotation)
      const sin = Math.sin(lineRotation)

      let x = ballx - innerWidth / 2 
      let y = bally - innerHeight / 2
      let vx1 = cos * ballvx + sin * ballvy
      let vy1 = cos * ballvy - sin * ballvx

      let y1 = cos * y - sin * x

      if (y1 > -ballRadius / 2 && y1 < vy1) {
        // debugger
        const x2 = cos * x + sin * y

        y1 = -ballRadius / 2
        vy1 *= -0.45

        x = cos * x2 - sin * y1
        y = cos * y1 + sin * x2

        ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 0] = cos * vx1 - sin * vy1
        ballsVelocitiesArray[i * 2 + 1] = cos * vy1 + sin * vx1

        ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 0] = innerWidth / 2 + x
        ballsOffsetsArray[i * 2 + 1] = innerHeight / 2 + y
      }
    }
  }
}

function resize () {
  canvas.width = innerWidth * dpr
  canvas.height = innerHeight * dpr
  canvas.style.width = `${innerWidth}px`
  canvas.style.height = `${innerHeight}px`
}

/* ------- WebGL helpers ------- */
function makeQuadUVs () {
  return new Float32Array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
}

function makeWebglShader (gl, { shaderType, shaderSource }) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(shaderType)
  gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource)
  gl.compileShader(shader)
  const success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)
  if (success) {
    return shader
  }
  console.error(`
    Error in ${shaderType === gl.VERTEX_SHADER ? 'vertex' : 'fragment'} shader:
    ${gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader)}
  `)
  gl.deleteShader(shader)
}

function makeWebglProram (gl, { vertexShader, fragmentShader }) {
  const program = gl.createProgram()
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)
  gl.linkProgram(program)
  const success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)
  if (success) {
    return program
  }
  console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program))
  gl.deleteProgram(program)
}

function makeProjectionMatrix (width, height) {
  return new Float32Array([
    2 / width, 0, 0, 0,
    0, -2 / height, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    -1, 1, 0, 1,
  ])
}

function showWebGL2NotSupported () {
  const errorMessageWrapper = document.createElement('div')
  if (isIOS()) {
    const iOSVersion = getIOSVersion().major
    if (iOSVersion === 13) {
      errorMessageWrapper.innerHTML = `
        <p>Please update your device to iOS / iPadOS 14 so you can see this demo.</p>
      `
    } else if (iOSVersion === 14) {
      errorMessageWrapper.innerHTML = `
        <p>In order to see WebGL2 content, you need to enable it from your device settings.</p>
        <p>Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental Features > WebGL2.0</p>
      `
    }
  } else {
    errorMessageWrapper.innerHTML = `
      <h1>Your browser does not support WebGL2</h1>
      <p>Please try one of these alternative browsers:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Microsoft Edge (version 79+)</li>
        <li>Mozilla Firefox (version 51+)</li>
        <li>Google Chrome (version 56+)</li>
        <li>Opera (version 43+)</li>
      </ul>
    `
  }
  errorMessageWrapper.classList.add('webgl2-error')
  document.body.appendChild(errorMessageWrapper)
}

/* ------- Generic helpers ------- */
function isMobileBrowser () {
  return (function (a) {
    if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera)
}

function isIOS () {
  return (/AppleWebKit/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Mobile\/\w+/.test(navigator.userAgent)) || isIPadOS()
}

function isIPadOS () {
  return navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1 && !window.MSStream
}

function getIOSVersion () {
  const found = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPad); (CPU iPhone|CPU) OS (\d+)_(\d+)(_(\d+))?\s+/)
  if (!found || found.length < 4) {
    return {
      major: 0,
      minor: 0
    }
  }
  return {
    major: parseInt(found[3], 10),
    minor: parseInt(found[4], 10)
  }
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

**EDIT**

By the first comment suggestion, I enabled the `EXT_color_buffer_float` and `OES_texture_float_linear` extensions and augmented my `texImage2D` call like this:

```
gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float')
gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear')

// ...

const targetTexture = gl.createTexture()
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture)
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32F, targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null)
```

Unfortunately this results in corrupted rendering on all of my browsers running on MacOS. I updated my code snippet to reflect the new changes.

I read in MDN's Webgl2 best practices that `EXT_float_blend` is also required in order to allow blending in framebuffers, but is implicitly allowed when requesting `EXT_color_buffer_float`?

On a sidenote, I guess the `OES_texture_float_linear` would not work on mobile devices? So if the extension is not available, I would need to fallback to 8bit RGBA textures?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is the texture your rendering to is 8bits. Switch it to a floating point texture (`RGBA32F`) You'll need to check for and enable `EXT_color_buffer_float` and `OES_texture_float_linear`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @gman.

I tried enabling these extensions following MDN guides like this:

```
const ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float')
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.RGBA32F, 256, 256)

gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float')
gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear')
```

and then passing gl.FLOAT as type to my .texImage2D() call, but I am getting `invalid format` error. I tried using the RGBA32F format in my texImage2D call without much success

Comment: Why are you calling `renderbufferStorage`? To use floating point textures in WebGL2 pass `RGBA32F` as the internal format and `RGBA` as the format and `FLOAT` as the type to `texImage2D`. Also there is no such extension `OES_texture_float` in WebGL2

Comment: Unfortunately I get corrupted rendering by introducing these extensions and `RGBA32` texture format. I updated my question and code snippet to reflect your changes. Thanks again for your time @gman

Comment: Posted an answer the covers the corruption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue the texture your rendering to is 8bits. Switch it to a floating point texture (`RGBA32F`) You'll need to check for and enable `EXT_color_buffer_float` and `OES_texture_float_linear`

## Update

You say it won't work on mobile but you're using WebGL2 which hasn't shipped on iPhone yet (2021/1/3). As for RGBA32F not being renderable on mobile you could try RGBA16F. You'll have to check for and enable the corresponding extensions, `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` and `OES_texture_half_float_linear`.  Your current code is not checking that the extensions actually exist (I'm assuming that was just to keep the code minimal)

The corruption is that your circle calculation draws alpha < 0 outside the circle but inside the quad. Before that was getting clipped to 0 because of the texture format but now with floating point textures it's not so it affects other circles.

Either `discard` if `c` <= 0 or clamp so it doesn't go below 0.

Note: you might find coloring faster and more flexible using [a ramp texture](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-ramp-textures.html). [example](https://jsgist.org/?src=a16cc514825b63739d7f40c4ff0d334e), [example2](https://jsgist.org/?src=f46488ffae1002725f84bb7fd233c3ed)

Also note: It would have been nice if you'd created a more minimal repo. There's no need for the animation to show either issue

## Update 2

Something else to point out, maybe you already knew this, but, the circle calculation

```
    float dist = distance(v_uv, vec2(0.5));
    float c = 0.5 - dist;
```

means the max value is 0.5 so half the range is being thrown away.

Switching to this

```
    float dist = distance(v_uv, vec2(0.5)) * 2.0;
    float c = 1.0 - dist;
```

Changes the range from 0 to 1 which is arguably better for shading later and to not throw away a bunch of precision in the texture. [Example](https://jsgist.org/?src=5bb48c7b0ea7137be55f87b9c245436f)

Comment: and one small additional question: is it safe to fallback to `RGBA16F` if the `EXT_color_buffer_float` extension is not present? or should the fallback be a part of another check?

Comment: `EXT_color_buffer_float` is not related to `RGBA16F`. you want `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` to be able to render to `RGBA16F`. You can check your phones for that at easily at [https://webglreport.com/](https://webglreport.com/). My iPhone6S+ has it (5yrs old) but, like I mentioned in the answer, you'll need to switch to WebGL1 if you want it work on iPhone right now. Or pray that Apple ships WebGL2 without a flag.

Comment: Also note if you switch to WebGL1 the way you setup float or half float textures is different. WebGL2 internalformat = `RGBA32F`, format = `RGBA`, type = `FLOAT` or internalformat = `RGBA16F`, format = `RGBA`, type = `HALF_FLOAT`. WebGL1 internalformat = `RGBA`, format = `RGBA`, type = `FLOAT` or internalformat = `RGBA`, format = `RGBA`, type = `HALF_FLOAT_OES` and in WebGL1 you need to check for and enable `OES_texture_float` or `OES_texture_half_float` plus the corresponding ones for rendering and filtering.